# Unable to connect to remote SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, databasepublishingwizard

I have created my asp.net website using database ASPNETDB.MDF but when I try to host my site on server ...

The SQL Server 2005 hosting provider issue me the

```
database name dobriyalji 
server ip : 69.112.222.220
database username : XXXX
database password : XXXX
```

I have imported all of my ASPNETDB.MDF tables to my server database dobriyalji ...

And I empty the Appdata.mdf and aspnetdb.log file from App_Data Folder ...

When I try to run my site the following error occurs ...

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file 
>   Users\Ashish Dobriyal\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\WebSites\VOLVO\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF
>
> failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot
>   be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

***MY LOCALHOST CONNECTION STRING :***

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

**MY REMOTE HOST CONNECTION STRING :**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="vbi_india2kConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=69.112.222.220;Initial Catalog=dobriyalji;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Password=XXXX" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i HAVE UPDATED MY CONNECTION STRING ...

Comment: Connection string still references the mdf file, but you're not using mdf anymore, you're using sql 2005

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [publish database wizard](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/11/04/deploying-the-aspnetdb-mdf-to-a-production-server.aspx) to deploy [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to your production database server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the physical mdf / ldf files from your development machine. Assuming you do as the error "specified file cannot be opened" is quite clear. So are you on a shared SQL Server with other sites; if so is there a database on the sql server called aspnetdb? You may have to change the name of your database as you attach it in order to get it onto the sql server.

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'myASPNetDB', 
   @filename1 = N'c:\mypathdata\myaspnet.mdf', 
   @filename2 = N'c:\mypathlogs\myaspnet_log.ldf'
```